# How can I disable the right click event or how can I hide the context menu on the Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: events, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

How can ı disable right click event on autodesk forge viewer. I want to hide the context menu.Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to disable context menu, just set null to setContextMenu method.

```
viewer.setContextMenu(null);
```

if you would like to show context menu again, you just  preserve context and set it.

```
// you need to get current context menu before calling setsetContextMenu(null)
var contextMenu = viewer.contextmenu;  
viewer.setContextMenu(null);


....

//set preserved contextMenu inf you want to show it again.
viewer.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

Comment: viewer.setContextMenu(null); helped. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide context menu use this:

```
viewer.contextMenu.hide();
```

If you want to remove context menu items, and add your own context menu use this:

You can remove default **Autodesk Forge Viewer Context menu** by `this.viewer.unregisterContextMenuCallback('Autodesk.Dasher.ContextMenuExtension');`
And you can create on your own by

```
    this.viewer.registerContextMenuCallback('Autodesk.Dasher.ContextMenuExtension',
(menu, status) => {}
```

REFERENCE : [HOW TO ADD CUSTOM CONTEXT IN FORGE VIEWER](https://www.keanw.com/2016/11/removing-context-menu-commands-in-the-forge-viewer.html).
Here is sample class for removing and adding your own custom context menu in Forge Viewer:

```
    export default class ContextMenuExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    
      constructor(viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, options: any) {
    
        super(viewer, options);
}
      load(): boolean {
    
        console.log('ContextMenuExtension loaded');
    
        let self = this;
    
        this.viewer.registerContextMenuCallback(
    
          'Autodesk.Dasher.ContextMenuExtension',
    
          (menu, status) => {
            // Remove all existing menu items
            while (menu.length > 0) {
              menu.pop();
            }
    
            // Add our new item if an object is selected
            if (status.hasSelected) {
              menu.push({
    
                title: 'Send to HoloLens',
                target: function(): void {
                  let messageSpecs = {
                    'msgTitleKey': 'Sent to HoloLens',
                    'messageKey': 'Sent to HoloLens',
                    'messageDefaultValue': 'This object has been sent to HoloLens for viewing.',
                  };
                  Autodesk.Viewing.Private.HudMessage.displayMessage(
    
                    self.viewer.container, messageSpecs
    
                  );

                  setTimeout(
                    () => {
                      Autodesk.Viewing.Private.HudMessage.dismiss();
                    }, 10000
                  );
                },
              });
            }
          }
        );
    
        return true;
      }
      unload(): boolean {
    
        console.log('ContextMenuExtension unloaded');
    
        this.viewer.unregisterContextMenuCallback('Autodesk.Dasher.ContextMenuExtension');
    
        return true;
      }
    }
```